Return an array of objects from a C function?
I'd like to know how to return an array of objects from a C function.
Here's an example:
SDL_Vertex initTriangle (struct Point2D point1, struct Point2D point2, struct Point2D point3) {
   SDL_Vertex triangleVertex[3]=
        {
            {
                { new_point1.x,new_point1.y },
                { 255, 255, 0, 0xFF },
                { 0.f, 0.f }
            },
            {
                { new_point2.x, new_point2.y },
                { 0,255,255, 0xFF },
                { 0.f, 0.f }
            },
            {
                { new_point3.x, new_point3.y },
                { 255,0,255, 0xFF },
                { 0.f, 0.f }
            }
        };
   return triangleVertex;
};

SDL_Vertex triangleVertex[3] = initTriangle(...);
SDL_RenderGeometry(renderer, NULL, triangleVertex, 3, NULL, 0);

I'd like to do something like that, but I need to make the function return an object as if I was making this :
SDL_Vertex triangleVertex[3]=
        {
            {
                { new_point1.x,new_point1.y },
                { 255, 255, 0, 0xFF },
                { 0.f, 0.f }
            },
            {
                { new_point2.x, new_point2.y },
                { 0,255,255, 0xFF },
                { 0.f, 0.f }
            },
            {
                { new_point3.x, new_point3.y },
                { 255,0,255, 0xFF },
                { 0.f, 0.f }
            }
        };
SDL_RenderGeometry(renderer, NULL, triangleVertex, 3, NULL, 0);


You can return an array from a function but you can't allocate it on the stack as your example shows. You have to allocate it on the heap.

The only way to return an array from a function is to embed it in a struct. struct EmbedArray { int a[10]; }; struct EmbedArray foo(int init) { struct EmbedArray ret; for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ret.a[i] = init; return ret; } see https://ideone.com/Xu0Iyn

You cannot return an array from a function.  You can allocate data and return a pointer to the first element, or you can return a struct than contains an array, but you cannot return an array.

This question is similar to: Returning an array using C. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also, what @pmg said: Something like  typedef struct { SDL_Vertex vertices[3]; } VertexTriplet; might do the trick for you - and you can return it from your function.

It looks like you want initTriangle to return an array of 3 SDL_Vertexs.
You cannot return an array this way (by value) from a C function.
One solution would be to accept it as a parameter and fill it in the function:
void initTriangle (struct Point2D new_point1, 
                   struct Point2D new_point2, 
                   struct Point2D new_point3, 
                   SDL_Vertex triangleVertex[3])  // <- add this parameter
{
    // Fill the array passed in:
    triangleVertex[0] = 
            (SDL_Vertex)  // This cast might be needed
            {
                { new_point1.x,new_point1.y },
                { 255, 255, 0, 0xFF },
                { 0.f, 0.f }
            };
    triangleVertex[1] = 
            (SDL_Vertex)  // This cast might be needed
            {
                { new_point2.x, new_point2.y },
                { 0,255,255, 0xFF },
                { 0.f, 0.f }
            };
    triangleVertex[2] = 
            (SDL_Vertex)  // This cast might be needed
            {
                { new_point3.x, new_point3.y },
                { 255,0,255, 0xFF },
                { 0.f, 0.f }
            };
};

Example for usage (the array of the caller is passed as the last argument):
SDL_Vertex myTriangleVertex[3];
initTriangle(..., myTriangleVertex);  

Another alternative is to allocate the array inside the function on the heap, and return it. But this would require the caller to remember to deallocate the array to avoid a memory leak.
A third alternative is to embed the array in a struct and then you'll be able to return it from the function.
But in this case I would go with the first solution I suggested (at least by default), being the simplest one.

Thank you a lot, I'll give it a try. I think I already tried in the past but gcc was telling me that I can't allocate triangleVertex[0] this way (with a '='). And that an expression was expected.
I'll let you know if I succeed.

As I said, gcc give me this error : "error: expected expression before '{' token". I'm not sure why, could you help me ?
It occurs here :
"
triangleVertex[0] =
{
"

There was a typo in the name of the parameters (the error exists in the code you posted as well and I copied it without checking). Also it seems like with certain versions you need to cast the aggregate when assigning. See demo. Updated my answer, please let me know if it helped.

It worked as expected, thank you a lot !
